# Convert ASHX ProcessRequest to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ashx

I have an ashx file with the following method defined:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) ...
```

I want to move the code inside of it into an MVC controller. It's all code that can be easily run as-is in an MVC controller, but I'm not sure if I need to write it in a specific way to be able to get called the same way. I've tried the following:

```
[HttpPost] //in the TestController
public void Index()
{
    var context = HttpContext;
....
```

But it doesn't hit my breakpoint on the first line. Is there another way I need to set it up in order to replicate being called as `ProcessRequest` is called in an ASHX file?

EDIT: here's my route config:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Test",
        url: "test/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Comment: Check your routing and make sure your post is hitting the controller/action.  What is the url that the client is calling?

Comment: Just the root of the controller since it's index and the route is specified with Index as the default. I edited the post to add the Route.

Comment: Can you use Fiddler or Postman to manually post to that endpoint?  How is the endpoint being called?  Can you create a GET Index action and browse to it by url?  If you can get to it manually, then the issue is the client call.

Comment: The issue was that the application making the call to it was making a GET, not a POST as I'd wrongly assumed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for my purposes, my action method had to be a GET, not a POST. Changing that fixed my problem.